# What causes intermittent hidded_service connectivity? Is there a way to stablize it?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Certain clients cannot connect to my hidden_service. I have no errors in any log, just

```
connection timed out
```

in the tor browser. If I try from a different device, it can reach the hidden_service url/.onion fine. Both devices can browse other tor sites just fine.

What causes intermittent tor hidden_service? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

from irc.oftc.net #tor

The issues comes from v2.0 custom addresses. If you want a custom url, you're going to lose connectivity reliability.

v3.0 (your default) will not experience the same problems.

If you absolutely must use a custom v2.0 address, you must develop a schema that incorporates the use of both v2.0 and v3.0 such as hyperlink anchor tag being v2.0 and using an actual v3.0 address, on twin servers. Prepare for v2.0 unreliability.